# What to do if the plans are unverified

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

My app has several training, out of which few are showing as unverified. Not able to understand what's wrong?
My action file is

> FoodSearch.model.bxb

```
action (FoodSearch) {
  type(Search)
   collect{
    input (dateTimeExpression) {
      type (time.DateTimeExpression)//MyDateTimeExpression
      min (Optional)
    }

    input (cityName) {
      type (geo.NamedPoint)
      min (Optional) max (One)
      default-select {
        with-learning
       with-rule {
         select-first
      }
    }
  }
}
output (FoodConfirmationResult) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the suggested method listed in the documentation? Here is a link to it: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.intro-training

> **Unverified Plan:** The training entry's current plan differs in a
>   nontrivial way from the plan at the time this entry was saved. This
>   can happen when model changes make the training entry's plan behave
>   differently from the last time it was saved. You can resolve this by
>   ensuring the plan for the entry is correct and recompiling the NL
>   model, or by running Verify All Plans.

You can verify plans by

> **Verifying Plans** You can clear "Unverified Plan" statuses by selecting
>   the ***Verify All Plans*** command in the Training Action menu (the dropdown
>   menu under the "Compile NL Model" button). This command asserts that
>   the plans for all complete, legal and enabled entries are correct. It
>   will create a new plan from the Aligned NL for each entry, based on
>   the current state of your capsule's models, vocabulary, and other
>   data.
>
> The training status of each entry may change after running this
>   command. Disabled plans will not be verified.